# Can an inherited @property not satisfy a <protocol> @property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, cocoa-design-patterns

I've got a protocol:

```
@protocol Gadget <NSObject>

@property (readonly) UIView *view;

- (void) attachViewToParent:(UIView *)parentView;

@end
```

And an "abstract" base class, with an implementation (as a getter, not shown) of `-(UIView *)view`:

```
// Base functionality
@interface AbstractGadget : NSObject {
    UIView *view;
}

@property (readonly) UIView *view;

@end
```

But when I implement the `Gadget` protocol in a subclass of `AbstractGadget`, like so:

```
// Concrete
@interface BlueGadget : AbstractGadget <Gadget> {
}

- (void) attachViewToParent:(UIView *)parentView;

@end


@implementation BlueGadget

- (void) attachViewToParent:(UIView *)parentView {
    //...
}

@end
```

I get a compiler error telling me "*warning: property 'view' requires method '-view' to be defined*." I can make this go away using `@dynamic`, or adding a stub method:

```
- (UIView *) view {
    return [super view];
}
```

But I just want to know if I'm doing something that's not supported, something I shouldn't be doing, or if it's just a limitation / bug in the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By declaring the property as @dynamic you are telling the compiler that the property getter (and setter if required) are implemented elsewhere (potentially at runtime).  This sounds like a perfectly reasonable use case to me.

See [The Docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9) for more information.

Comment: +1 the same as my answer but much better and with a link to the docs.

Comment: I'll have to test this with Clang and Xcode 4 when I can get my hands on them.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this exact issue.  This is one of situations that @dynamic is there for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule for variable, property and synthesize in objective-C:

If you have a property, you must have a @synthesize or you declare @dynamic and write the getter and setter method yourself.

So, because you have a property called view, you have to declare @synthesize. That should be it. Nothing to do with @protocol, inheritance

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. There's a complete implementation of "-(UIView *) view" in AbstractGadget.

Comment: Can you show me your code in AbstractGadget implementation as well. Something goes wrong now, because it usually works for me

Comment: Since the property is implemented in the base class you use @dynamic in the subclass.